# How do I limit specific column options to moderators?

Tags: discussion-board

I added a column "sticky" to create sticky threads and posts (I followed this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36855/Sticky-posts-in-SharePoint-Discussion-boards guide)

My questions is... how do I make the sticky option only available to moderators or administrators and not for a basic user?

I am running SharePoint 2007

---

Another extra question:
Are there any free extensions to make the 2007 discussion board have more/better functions and maybe improve its aesthetic look?

Comment: This really should be two different questions as they are largely unrelated

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is Column level security which SharePoint doesn't have.  There are some [third-party tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20160511220501/http://store.bamboosolutions.com:80/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx) that offer it or you can [roll your own](https://web.archive.org/web/20140523234000/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/g/archive/2009/01/22/column-level-security-in-sharepoint.aspx).

And, while I haven't actually done this, I have heard of some people using workflows to accomplish something similar.  I.e.. create a 'Sticky' workflow that will add its own column to the list and set the value when the workflow is run.

One other option would be to [create an Event Receiver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms453149%28v=office.14%29) to monitor the [ItemAdding and ItemUpdating](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648923%28v=pandp.10%29) events and then kick out an error if someone attempts to set 'Sticky' that does not have permissions.  This is not a good user experience but it is fairly simple to do.